# An installation that boots to the command line, with an option to load the desktop?

Tags: system-installation, configuration

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, what installation options I should choose?

Answer (score 0):

To change your install to boot straight to command line after install, you can just
Go to a terminal prompt..

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then make the following changes..

Change the lines containing..

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”  .. just put a # at the beginning 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console to GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Save and exit.

sudo update-grub

That will stop X from starting on boot. to start X, just type `startx`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [Ubuntu server edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server)? Follow the instructions on that page ([or this one from the 12.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html)) to install it, similar to a regular Ubuntu install but text-based.

And then install a desktop environment with a line like `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, or `sudo apt-get install xfce4` (the "Meta-package for the Xfce Lightweight Desktop Environment").

You could pick whichever desktop environment you prefer, there are a LOT to choose from. I'd pick XFCE. See [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: But wouldn't it boot straight to the desktop environment once you have installed that?